# Laravel DB queries help needed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am new in Laravel,
Having some difficulties to understand the queries

I have 2 tables

1. Users [id, email, fname , lname ]
2. Leads [id, other some fields, client, agent]

the client and agent is the foreign key of users table's id..

with the below code i can retrive datas from the Leads table
but there i get client = 3
agent = 4 something like this

but instead of showing those ids i want to get the names of those ids from the user table

how to do it?

In the controller i have this function as of now

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function leads(){

    if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){

        $leads = Leads::all();

        // here in the $leads i get datas like ['id' => 1, 'field1' => 'test', 'field2'=> 'test2', 'client_id'=> 2, 'agent_id'=> 3] , but i want to get the names of the client and agent from the user table which we can do in normal sql query by joining but how to do with laravel?

    }

    return view('leads', compact('leads'));
}
```

How it can be done ?

in the Users Model & Leads model i have only the default codes i have the code

will appreciate if get some quick help

Comment: You requirement is really confusing. From what i can gather, is that you want to show from an agent?

Comment: hi, thanks for a quick response, 
let me clarify you .

When ever a new lead is created it has the current agent id in the leads table's agent column, and same for the client

i have there id's but need to retrive the names of those clients or agents and need to show those in view 

thats it

Comment: Try to update the question and to clarify a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change your column names to `agent_id` & `client_id` instead of `agent` & `client`. Otherwise you need to update the following code accordingly.

Judging by your answer, i think you need to do something like this in `Leads` model:

#### Define relations for agent & client

```
public function agent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'agent_id');
}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'client_id');
}
```

#### Autoload them on every query call to Leads model.

```
protected $with = ['agent', 'client'];
```

After you do the above steps, you can simply list an agent/client for a lead by writing:

```
$lead->agent->name;
$lead->client->name;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, looks like the proper way going, but when i am returning the $leads from controller i can see all the datas, but in view not getting those

Comment: For some records, they might be empty. You need to validate if the value is empty or not.

Comment: I double checked, it looks like no data missing, but in view when i am passing the $leads variable through compact('leads') in the view in foreach loop i see the $lead->client giving the id, not the client data(object) what i can see in the controller, what could be the reason for this can you please say?

Comment: You said that `agent` & `client` fields are actually user ids from users table. You need to write `$lead->client->name` etc. Also check fillable properies for `User` model.

Comment: ->name not accessible as the $lead->client is returning integer in view.

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property of non-object (View: F:\xampp7\htdocs\laravel\crm\resources\views\leads.blade.php)

Comment: hi, after printing with dd(). i found this
finally those are being accessible by this way in view or in controlled too

{{$lead->relationsToArray()['client']['name']}}

please if possible tell me why its not being accessible public ?

Comment: Why would you put the relations in plural and not in singular to make it more clear that it will return just one record?

Comment: Because his column names are singular, not postfixed by something like `_id`.

Comment: got it, and finally it worked fully, thanks a lot for all the helps